# How to start httpd service using ansible module on Centos

Tags: apache, ansible

I am suing passphrase protected SSL certificate for my Apache server. Whenever I try to restart the Apache server is is asking for passphrase, I can enter the passphrase manually however how to restart the service using Ansible module (either systemd or command)? How can I pass my passphrse in ansible to start the service?

Answer (score 0):

To make apache receive the passphrase everytime it restarts, add this to the `httpd.conf`:

```
SSLPassPhraseDialog exec:/path/to/passphrase-file
```

and in your `/path/to/passphrase-file` file:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "the passphrase"
```

answer from https://serverfault.com/questions/71043/ssl-password-on-apache2-restart

Comment: Thanks but I want to avoid saving the passphrase on Server, is there anyway Ansible can read the passphrase from Vault?

Comment: Ansible can read the passphrase from Vault if you store the value, the question is how you plan to pass it to the apache start command? from the linked thread seems the way to go is the one i mentioned in the answer. and for your security concerns, you could do these: 1. generate the passphrase file on the server, 2. run the http start command and 3. delete the passphrase file from the server.